# How do i multiply it correctly, currently printing it differently

Tags: python

```
numero = input('Montako lukua?')

sum = 0
for sum in numero:
    sum = int(numero * 10)

print(sum)
```

currently it is printing `33333` when I type `3` in terminal when I want it to be `30`

Comment: You are first performing a string multiplication and only then converting it into an integer. You want it in reversed order: `int(numero) * 10`.

Comment: Also, note that you are overwriting `sum = 0` immediately after declaring it by using it as the variable in your loop. That line is currently meaningless.

Comment: `input()` always gives string and you have to convert it to integer before you multiply.

Comment: Don't use sum as a variable name it is a reserved keywords of the language. You are overriding it's definition.